# creating z-scores

Tags: r

I have a data file consisting of 57 variables. I want to transform about 12 of them into z-scores due to their uneven level of measurement. I looked up internet resources and help files. One internet resource adviced that I need the package Rbasic (does not exist). I used scale() which only seemed to center the variables. I tried V5-mean/st.dev. which got me very strange scores. Can somebody please give me practical adivce?

Comment: scale does center AND scale if you ask it. Read the help page.

Comment: Don't even have to ask it since it is the default right?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`scale()` is the correct choice here:

```
> x <- 1:10
> scale(x)
            [,1]
 [1,] -1.4863011
 [2,] -1.1560120
 [3,] -0.8257228
 [4,] -0.4954337
 [5,] -0.1651446
 [6,]  0.1651446
 [7,]  0.4954337
 [8,]  0.8257228
 [9,]  1.1560120
[10,]  1.4863011
attr(,"scaled:center")
[1] 5.5
attr(,"scaled:scale")
[1] 3.02765
> (x - mean(x)) / sd(x)
 [1] -1.4863011 -1.1560120 -0.8257228 -0.4954337 -0.1651446
 [6]  0.1651446  0.4954337  0.8257228  1.1560120  1.4863011
> mean(x)
[1] 5.5
> sd(x)
[1] 3.02765
```

Notice how the attributes in the object returned from `scale()` are the mean and SD of the input data.

Now you don't provide real code to show how you computed "V5-mean/st.dev" but if you did it exactly like that the operator precedence might have caught you out. This for example doesn't return the correct z-scores:

```
> x - mean(x) / sd(x)
 [1] -0.8165902  0.1834098  1.1834098  2.1834098  3.1834098
 [6]  4.1834098  5.1834098  6.1834098  7.1834098  8.1834098
```

Comment: very good point on the precedence, thats caught me out a number of times.

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what happened: When I used (V5-mean)/sd, the values differed from those that PAWS gave me.

Comment: @gavin: I apologize that I ticked this response so late. I became only recently aware that responses are being voted for.

Answer (score 3):

```
mu <- mean(myRow) 

sigma   <- sqrt ( var(myRow)  )

myRow <- (myRow - mu )/ sqrt(sigma)
```

Comment: Something isn't quite right there. `sigma` can be computed using `sd()`. Then you use the square root of `sigma` to standardise the data.

Comment: Use `scale`. It's way easier.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you forgot the brackets in:  x - mean(x)/sd(x)

The correct code is: **(** x - mean(x) **)** /sd(x)