# calculate mean of z score in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Hi for some uni homework I have to:

Create a new variable containing the z-score of gender_fem
Calculate the mean of this z-score for each group in the gender variable

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2WWg.png)

Code attempt:

````
    ```{r} 
gensex %>%
  dplyr::mutate(gender_fem_z = scale(gender_fem)) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(gender) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(mean_gender_fem_z = mean(gender_fem_z))
  
```
````

Not sure if what I've done is correct or not I'm brand new to R so basically clueless.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are using R markdown, not just R.

In case that is the "problem", you only need to change the code to this:

```
gensex %>%
  dplyr::mutate(gender_fem_z = scale(gender_fem)) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(gender) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(mean_gender_fem_z = mean(gender_fem_z))
```

Also, please take a look here:
[creating z-scores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148050/creating-z-scores)

Basically, the z-score follows this formula: `x - mean(x) / sd(x)` which is written in R